# Establecer que todos los campos que llenen en la grid sean string C# + Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un problema al llenar un datagridview y es que al llenarlo desaparecen algunos datos en algunas celdas, y creo que es porque se establecen con un formato predeterminado por el mismo datagrid al llenarse, quisiera saber como hacer para que todos los datos los traiga como string o como selecionar un formato por columnas.

Añado Codigo (recojo los datos que hay en un excel y los añado en un datagrid)

```
//Aqui pregunto por la direccion donde esta el excel

DialogResult ListaUbiExcel = buscarlist.ShowDialog();

//Con esto valido la direccion y continuo con la sentencia

//dtgrilla es el nombre del DataGridView

if (ListaUbiExcel == DialogResult.OK)

               {
                    buscarlist.Title = "Selecciona el archivo excel (xls, xlsx)";
                    buscarlist.Filter = "*.xls|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    dtgrilla.Enabled = false;
                    string Direccion = buscarlist.FileName;
                    String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLeDb.4.0;Data Source= " + Direccion + ";Extended Properties= \"Excel 8.0;HDR = YES\"";  //Se crea el texto para la conexíón
                    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                    objConn.Open();
                    DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    OleDbCommand consultar = default(OleDbCommand);
                    consultar = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Hoja1$]", objConn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter lista = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    lista.SelectCommand = consultar;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    lista.Fill(ds);
                    dtgrilla.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    objConn.Close();
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues a tu pregunta, parte del código que tiene, para analizarlo y poder darte una respuesta...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes agregar un ejemplo? mira [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ya logre solucionarlo, incluso hacer el codigo mas sencillo aún, utilize Linq To Excel, para conectar con excel directamente, la libreria se consigue instalandola con el Manager NuGet de Visual Studio:**

> Clase: Entidad Hoja excel

```
class EntidadHojaExcel
{
   public string Pagina { get; set; }
   public string Material { get; set; }
   public string Descripcion { get; set; }
   public string Linea_Grabacion { get; set; }
   public string Catalogo { get; set; }
   public string Color { get; set; }
   public string Talla { get; set; }
}
```

> Clase: Listar Excel

```
            //BuscarList Es un objeto OpenFileDialog(Me sirve para buscar un archivo en el equipo)

            buscarlist.Title = "Selecciona el archivo excel (xls, xlsx)";
            buscarlist.Filter = "*.xls|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            DialogResult ListaUbiExcel = buscarlist.ShowDialog();
            string Direccion = buscarlist.FileName;

            //Entra si el usuario selecciona un archivo

            if (ListaUbiExcel == DialogResult.OK)
            {  

            var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(Direccion);
                            var resultado = (from row in book.Worksheet("Hoja1")
                             let item = new EntidadHojaExcel
                             {
                                 Pagina = row[0].Cast<string>(),
                                 Material = row[1].Cast<string>(),
                                 Descripcion = row[2].Cast<string>(),
                                 Linea_Grabacion = row[3].Cast<string>(),
                                 Catalogo = row[4].Cast<string>(),
                                 Color = row[5].Cast<string>(),
                                 Talla = row[6].Cast<string>()
                             }
                             select item).ToList();
            book.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Cargado con Exito", "El documento se ha cargado", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            //DataGrilla es el nombre del datagrid                

            dtgrilla.DataSource = resultado;
            dtgrilla.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Answer (score 2):

El DataGridView por defecto te llena todas las columnas que traiga tu DataSource. Para evitar esto modifica la propiedad AutoGenerateColumns a false. Solo recuerda que cuando esta propiedad está en false, debes tu mismo indicarle al DataGridView que columnas vas a mostrar y el tipo de dato, esto puedes hacerlo en diseño o en código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta pero el datagrid se llena desde un excel,asi que las columnas no las defino yo, las define el archivo excel.

Comment: @AndresM justamente, en esta respuesta se te explica como evitar eso y que vos decidas el tipo de cada columna. Si esto no es lo que buscas, por favor aclaralo en la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me hiciste replantearme hacerlo de otra forma, abajo esta el codigo por si quieres ver como lo solucione.